# Undo rake assets:clean/precompile RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a rails app with bootstrap. I was trying to change my header and ran `rake assets:precompile` but this changed my menu.

[image]

The menu is now stacked

It should look like:

[image]

I tried running `rake assets:clean` but it didn't fix it back to one line for the menu. I also tried checking out an old commit, but the problem is still there. thanks

Answer (score 0):

There could be different reasons:

> You may have multiple references in stylesheets to apply styles to
>   shown menu items and both could be different. So, it would be choosing
>   a wrong one.

OR

> The wrong order of css files to be pre-compiled given in manifest file
>   (application.css). Please do it in proper order as in this specific
>   order the pre-compilation will be done and loaded in DOM

Hope it helps :)